# Reset Ajax Header width when window resized without calling server side function

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatable

Is there any way to Reset Ajax Header width on window resized without calling server side function.

I have tried following code; it works but it reload the table when-ever called.

```
$('#dataTable').DataTable().columns.adjust().draw();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue Solved

```
$('#dataTable').dataTable().fnAdjustColumnSizing(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
                var fixedHeaders = [];
                $(table).each(function () {
                    fixedHeaders.push(
                        new $.fn.dataTable.FixedHeader(table, {
                            "offsetTop": 220, 
                            "zTop": "1"
                        })
                    );
                });

                $(window).resize(function () {
                    for (var i = 0; i < fixedHeaders.length; i++) {
                        fixedHeaders[i]._fnUpdateClones(true); // force redraw
                        fixedHeaders[i]._fnUpdatePositions();
                    }
                });
```